# Assign variables from array in for loop VBScript/Classic ASP

Tags: arrays, loops, vbscript, asp-classic

I have a for loop which iterates through an array generated from a CSV file.  This creates an array with either 1, 2 or 3 sets of numbers.  Problem is, I need to assign these a variable as I need to use them later on in a web form.  Also; sometimes there may be only 1 set of numbers in the array (so only array(1) would be possible).  How would I assign the dynamic array to individual variables - ie - YXVal, RXVal and GXVal  for X and YYVal, RYVAL and GYVal for Y - but if there is only 1 in the array it would be YXVal and YYVal.

```
Do while NOT objTextFile.AtEndOfStream
    arrStr = split(objTextFile.ReadLine,",")
    for x = 1 to ubound(arrStr) 
        if arrStr(0) = "x" Then         
            Xval = arrStr(x)            
            response.write(XVal & "<br />")
        end if
    next    
    for y = 1 to ubound(arrStr)
        if arrStr(0) = "y" Then
            Yval = arrStr(y)            
            response.write(YVal & "<br />")
        end if
    next                
Loop
```

Comment: Are you expecting _one_ occurrence of `"x"` and `"y"` in the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a straightforward way. If you expect *many* occurrences of `"x"` and `"y"` and you need to process each occurrence, you should reinitialize your variable values at the start of each iteration. Otherwise, they may still contain values from the *last* iteration.

```
Do Until objTextFile.AtEndOfStream

    ' Reinitialize variable values. This may be optional, depending on your needs.
    YXVal = "" : RXVal = "" : GXVal = "" : YYVal = "" : RYVal = "" : GYVal = ""

    ' Read a line...
    arrStr = Split(objTextFile.ReadLine, ",")
    intSize = UBound(arrStr)

    If intSize >= 0 Then

        ' Parse line values...
        Select Case LCase(arrStr(0))
            Case "x"
                If intSize > 0 Then YXVal = arrStr(1)
                If intSize > 1 Then RXVal = arrStr(2)
                If intSize > 2 Then GXVal = arrStr(3)
            Case "y"
                If intSize > 0 Then YYVal = arrStr(1)
                If intSize > 1 Then RYVal = arrStr(2)
                If intSize > 2 Then GYVal = arrStr(3)
        End Select

    End If

Loop
```

Comment: Many thanks - there is usually either 1 or 3 results, I suspect 2 wouldn't ever turn up, but using your code I keep getting an error on the line `Select Case LCase(arrStr(0))` error code is `Subscript out of range: '[number: 0]'`

Comment: You probably have a blank line in your source file. I've added an `If` statement to test for it.

Comment: Spot on -- it's the simple things that confuse me :)